# Codeception mock, how to provide list of method arguments

Tags: codeception

Codeception providing pretty easy and nice API for creating stubs/mocks https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Mock, but I do not see a way how to pass method arguments if I want to mock only specific method call.

An alternative way is to use mock builder like this:

```
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Class::class)->getMock();
    $mock->method('send')->with($request)->willReturn($response);
```

as you can see in mock builder there is a method `with`, but I can't find something similar in the API provided by codeception.

Is there a way to provide method arguments using codeception mocking API, or I need to use mock builder?

Comment: Use MockBuilder

Comment: yeah, that what I'm doing now, thanks!